# SQL Logic and Aggregate Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem to solve in SQL :

> d) A query that provides management information on take up of the various types of activities on offer. For each type of activity, the query should show the total number of individuals who took that type of activity and the average number of individuals taking each type of activity.

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE accommodations
(
chalet_number int PRIMARY KEY,
chalet_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
no_it_sleeps number(2) NOT NULL,
indivppw number(4) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE supervisors
(
supervisor_number int PRIMARY KEY,
supervisor_forename varchar(30) NOT NULL,
supervisor_surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
mobile_number varchar(11) NOT NULL
)



CREATE TABLE visitors
(
visitor_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
group_ID int NOT NULL,
forename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
gender varchar(1) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE activities
(
activity_code varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
activity_title varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"type" varchar(20) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE "groups"
(
group_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
group_leader varchar(20) NOT NULL,
group_name varchar(30)
number_in_group number(2) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE bookings
(
group_ID int NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL,
chalet_number int NOT NULL,
no_in_chalet number(2) NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL,
end_date date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT bookings_pk PRIMARY KEY(group_ID, chalet_number));


CREATE TABLE schedule
(
schedule_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
activity_code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
time_of_activity number(4,2) NOT NULL,
am_pm varchar(2) NOT NULL,
"date" date NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE activity_bookings
(
visitor_ID int NOT NULL,
schedule_ID int NOT NULL,
supervisor_number int NOT NULL,
comments varchar(200),
CONSTRAINT event_booking_pk PRIMARY KEY(visitor_ID, schedule_ID));





ALTER TABLE visitors
ADD FOREIGN KEY (group_ID)
REFERENCES "groups"(group_ID)

ALTER TABLE Schedule
ADD FOREIGN KEY (activity_code)
REFERENCES activities(activity_code)


ALTER TABLE bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (group_ID)
REFERENCES "groups"(group_ID)


ALTER TABLE bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (chalet_number)
REFERENCES accommodations(chalet_number)



ALTER TABLE activity_bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (visitor_ID)
REFERENCES visitors(visitor_ID)


ALTER TABLE activity_bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (schedule_ID)
REFERENCES schedule(schedule_ID)


ALTER TABLE activity_bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_number)
REFERENCES supervisors(supervisor_number)
```

I have the following solution:

```
SELECT activities."type", 'overalltotal' AS OT, ('overalltotal' / 'activities') AS AVG
  FROM activities, schedule
  WHERE 'overalltotal' = (SELECT SUM(COUNT(schedule_ID))
        FROM activities, schedule
        WHERE schedule.activity_code = activities.activity_code
        GROUP BY activities."type"
        )
  AND 'activities' = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT activities."type")
        FROM activities
        )
  AND schedule.activity_code = activities.activity_code
GROUP BY activities."type";
```

I have implemented sample data and code to check the variables above:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(schedule_ID))
        FROM activities, schedule
        WHERE schedule.activity_code = activities.activity_code
        GROUP BY activities."type";
```

> Result : 20

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT activities."type")
FROM activities;
```

> Result : 5

However when running the code :

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

EDIT:

Using Dave's Code i have the following output:

```
Snowboarding    15
sledding            19
Snowmobiling    6
Ice Skating         5
Skiing          24
```

How would i do the final part of the question?

> and the average number of individuals taking each type of activity.

Comment: But you can have multiple people scheduled at the same time. I think that's why you can have that many people going to activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use double quotes around column names in Oracle, not single quotes. For example, `"overalltotal"`. Single quotes are for text strings, which is why you're getting an invalid number error.

EDIT: This is probably the type of query you want to use:

```
SELECT activities."type", COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(*)/(COUNT(*) OVER ()) AS "avg"
FROM activities a
JOIN schedule s ON a.activity_code=s.activity_code
JOIN activity_bookings ab ON s.schedule_ID=ab.schedule_ID
GROUP BY activities."type";
```

Basically, because each activity booking has one visitor id, we want to get all the activity bookings for each activity. We have to go through schedule to do that. They we group the rows by the activity type and count how many activity bookings we have for each type.

Comment: no luck changed them and i get `ORA-00904: "activities": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 6`

Comment: That's probably because you already have a table named `activities`. You can't have a table and a column named the same thing. Looking more closely at your query there's some other problems with it. I need to thing about it a little more to rewrite it.

Comment: I believe David is attempting in-line assignments MySQL-style.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was curious about.

Comment: @Dave_Johnson Thanks I tried to change the variable and it still says invalid

Comment: @DaveJohnson Thanks, sorry to be a pain would it be possible to take me through this to explain how it is giving me the answers it is

Comment: Okay, I understand what you meant by average. I fixed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25820/discussion-between-dave-johnson-and-david-passmore)